# Cyrillic fonts imitating the look of other writing systems (e.g. Latin, Arabic)

Tags: typography

I mean something like [faux Cyrillic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faux_Cyrillic), but the other way round.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Russian language.

Comment: @Quassnoi I agree with you wholeheartedly. This is a question on a typography and definitely is (non-malevolent though) off-topic.

Comment: I haven't personally encountered such thing (as opposed to Faux Cyrillic), but it is common for children to mirror letters so that И becomes N and Я becomes R.

Comment: There are many Russian fonts that imitate Arabic. There are also the ones that imitate Gothic minuscule (Blackletter, Fraktur), and even those that look like Byzantine Greek majuscule and ancient Latin uncial.

Comment: In old days the western video games were "localized" by using Latin letters used to represent Russian texts like "Bbl Bu9uTE OKHO".